# onActivityResult() is not called in my main activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my main activity I call the second activity via button click in my toolbar like this

```
  if(id == R.id.addNav) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, TextFormActivity.class), 0);
        return true;
    }
```

Then in my second activity first I have constant for the tag

```
public static final String EXTRA_TEXT_ADD =
            "text_add";
```

Then when the add button was clicked I'm setting up the result

```
mButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Text text = new Text();
            text.setTitle(mEditTextTitle.getText().toString());
            text.setRecipient(mEditTextRecipient.getText().toString());
            text.setSent(false);
            text.setMessage(mEditTextMessage.getText().toString());
            mTextList.add(text);
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra(TextFormActivity.EXTRA_TEXT_ADD,true);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

        }
    });
```

This is how I handle things in onActivityResult

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("TextListActivity", "Result Entered");
        if(data == null){
            return;
        }
        boolean result = data.getBooleanExtra(TextFormActivity.EXTRA_TEXT_ADD,false);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Result Code: "+ result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I still don't know why my toast is not showing up when I'm returning to the main activity

**EDIT**
Well I already found the problem and that is I'm using  NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(TextFormActivity.this); to go back to the main activity and it does not call the method onActivityResult.

Comment: Is your debug message showing up in your logcat? If `data` were `null`, you'd not see your `Toast`. Are you even sure the result is being set properly in your other activity?

Comment: No it's not showing in the logcat. This is how i set it Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT_ADD,true);
setResult(RESULT_OK,i);

Comment: I set this inside a setOnclickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to finish the activity you started for result.

So in you button click listener after setting the result , just finish the activity.

```
mButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            .....
            ........
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra(TextFormActivity.EXTRA_TEXT_ADD,true);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();// finish the activity
        }
    });
```

Try this, should work.

Comment: yeah actually it works it called the onActivityResult but... I just got a new bug